# Silverlight and Search Engines

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, seo

I have recently started learning SilverLight (and Web developement in general) and have been advised by a friend that SilverLight isn't Search engine friendly (because Silverlight isn't HTML). Is there any way of getting around this and getting my site onto the Search engine lists (without paying)?

(Any advise on getting my site on search engines lists would be greatly appreciated).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

here are some great articles about SEO in SilverLight

http://www.plaveb.com/blog/how-to-optimize-silverlight-based-web-applications-for-search-engines

http://hatim.indexdev.net/2009/03/26/how-to-search-engine-optimize-a-silverlight-web-application/